# Delete all lines in all files in cPanel containing a string

Tags: php, replace, cpanel

I have a website with a lots of files. There is a faulty line of code in about 200 of them and I want to delete those lines. I do not want to do this manually because it would take me a lot of time. Is there a way to delete lines in files on a cPanel system containing a certain string?

Comment: ftp > download > find&replace (any decent text/code editor) > upload? or must this be done on the server

Comment: Unfortunately no. You can do a lot with shell access but I imagine you don't have that. Your best route will be to use something like Dreamweaver or [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/) to mass find/replace the files locally then push it all to the server in a big batch. You should also consider using dynamic scripting with a file inclusion strategy to prevent redundancy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates a backup of the files with the extension `.bak`, but still, be very careful:

```
foreach(glob('/path/to/files/*.ext') as $file) {
    copy($file, $file . '.bak');
    $data = file_get_contents($file);
    $data = str_replace('your string', '', $data);
    file_put_contents($file, $data);
}
```